# Охламон. Этимология

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова *охламон*?

Comment: Ваша версия какая? Какие версии не устраивают?

Comment: @shampar Интуиция Вас подводит. Вы с лёгкостью придираетесь и к хорошим (интересным и сложным) вопросам и к плохим / плохо сформулированным.

Comment: Непонятно о чём пишете. Разве от автора вопроса ожидать определённой внятности — есть придирка? Думаю, это должно быть нормой.

Comment: Автор интересуется этимологией слова. Вы требуете, чтобы он придумал несколько собственных версий любительской этимологии и объяснил, чем эти версии его не устраивают? Это не норма, это глупость.

Answer (score 2):

Людмила Кругликова, доктор филогических наук, научный сотрудник ИЛИ РАН, подробно и интересно рассказывает об этом [здесь](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=14.73). Просьба обратить внимание, что там 3 страницы текста, а не одна. (К сожалению, не могу скопировать цитату с основной мыслью, поскольку лень запрашивать письменное разрешение у авторов того источника. Благо, ссылками делиться даже самые злостные "копирасты" не запрещают.)

Если коротко, своими словами, то, скорее всего, слово происходит от греческих корней (буквально: один из толпы, ср. охлократия). Со временем слово существенно изменило своё значение, из-за чего стала популярной версия "народной этимологии" этого слова от "хлам". Причины понятны — каждому хочется поделиться первой пришедшей в голову ассоциацией, а у большинства она в данном случае совпадает.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего от "хлам".  "ОхлАмился" человек - голову" хламом "наполнил, образно говоря, и стал  "охламоном", то есть бестолочью. Примеры: обновиться - запастись обновками,  оглупеть - стать глупцом,  остолбенеть - застыть, подобно столбу и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что корни нужно искать в греческом языке. "охлос" - неорганизованное сборище людей + "монас" - древняя единица (измерения). Иными словами, охламоны - те, из кого состоит тупая агрессивная толпа. Бестолковый и легко внушаемый грубиян.